# Can't include &lt; in <code> in Wordpress Post

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm trying to publish a post that has code blocks in it. At first the published post would just show 'Nothing is Found Here'. I debugged it by testing out parts one by one. I identified the culprit but I don't know how to go about it.

It's basically this particular combination:

```
blablabla <code>&lt;form&gt;</code> blablabla
// which should display like below
blablabla <form> blablabla
```

it seems like including the special characters inside the `<code>` makes it crash

anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Please use following code to make it work:

```
blablabla [code language="html"]<form>[/code] blablabla
```